# Symbolizing route data using ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, symbology, routing, network-analyst

I'm working on a project that routes various modes of transport to one location (a school) in ArcMap 10. I have about 400 routes, so there is a significant amount of overlap as they near the school. Just for simplicity, let's say that 50 students walked, 150 drove and 200 took the bus.

What I'd like to is show the difference in modes of transport by widening the polylines as they overlap. And then, as they get close to 1 or 2 blocks from the school, have them all join. The line for students that walked to school would be 12.5%, students who drove would be 37.5%, and the students who bused would be 50%.

Can you think of a way I would be able to symbolize the data to show this?

It's a really specific problem I'm working on, so I've been having trouble coming up with the right solution. What I've done so far is separate the polylines that intersect, but that's where I'm stuck.